# Why does a date frame returning date with a time zone sometimes?

Tags: r, date, dataframe

I have a date frame such as:

```
head(mt, 3) 
                DateW       |         Date                       |          tempDeg 
2 2009-01-01 01:00:00       |         2009-01-01 01:00:00        |          -23.6 
3 2009-01-01 02:00:00       |         2009-01-01 02:00:00        |          -25.7 
4 2009-01-01 03:00:00       |         2009-01-01 03:00:00        |          -26.5 


mt[1,2] 
[1] "2009-01-01 01:00:00 MST"
```

Why does this return  a time with MST? I would like to keep my dates without timezones.

I built this data frame using the strptime function. Such as:

```
strptime(dateConv$DateTimeCNDW,format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
```

Comment: I hope that helps: `?strptime` says "strptime turns character representations into an object of class "POSIXlt". The timezone is used to set the isdst component and to set the "tzone" attribute if tz != "". If the specified time is invalid (for example "2010-02-30 08:00") all the components of the result are NA.". To switch it off, use `tz=""` or `usetz = F`.

Comment: POSIXlt and POSIXct objects have a timezone attribute by definition. If you see it depends on the `print` method.